# How to 301 redirect old query string?

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I have these old URLs:

```
/site/index?cat=likes&top=today
/site/index?cat=likes&top=month
/tag/TagName/index?cat=likes&top=today
```

I changed `cat=likes` to `cat=popular`

Now I'm getting 404's. How do I redirect all calls from cat=likes to cat=popular?

**Note:** I already have redirect that beautifies the URL.

`/site/index?cat=popular&top=today`

is already redirected to

`/popular-today`

Comment: If you think, this is a Yii issue, you should add the relevenat part of your url rules. If not, you should remove the Yii tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check wether the GET variable `cat` is set with the value 'likes', you can check this within your `site/index` or `tag/tagName`. After which you can redirect using PHP's `header()`. Something like this:

```
public function actionIndex()
{           
   if ($_GET['cat'] == 'likes') 
   {
      header('Location: /site/index?cat=popular', false, 301);
   }
   ...
}
```

You can also use your beautified URL.

```
public function actionIndex()
{           
   if ($_GET['cat'] == 'likes') 
   {
      header('Location: /popular-today', false, 301);
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: I currently have this entries in my .htaccess and is perfectly working:

`RedirectMatch 301 /tag/(.*)/likes-(today|week|month|year) /tag/$1/popular-$2
RedirectMatch 301 /tag/(.*)/likes-(new|all) /tag/$1/new
RedirectMatch 301 /tag/(.*)/likes-30 /tag/$1/popular-month
RedirectMatch 301 /likes-(today|week|month|year) /popular-$1`


I believe your suggestion would work but I'm looking more for a cleaner way of doing this outside the code.

So I want to know the proper .htaccess entries to redirect those query string in question.

Comment: that's probably a better sollution indeed, even though it doesn't have much to do with Yii.